# Search of Nexus | Sonatype isn't working

Tags: continuous-integration, hudson, nexus

Yesterday I updated the repository nexus that was in version 1.6 to latest version 1.9.2.3, doing merge all the configuration files and picking only other important settings.

Then we did several tests, publishing components, reducing artifacts and everything is working perfectly. The problem is that the search is not working, I try to get all that he can not find, the more the device is there, if I add a dependency that was not there and then he decides to be found in the search.

Has anyone experienced this? I would reindex the artifacts in storege?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like your repository's index needs to be [rebuilt](http://www.sonatype.com/books/nexus-book/reference/archiva-sect-migrating-managed.html#figu-archiva-nx-hosted-idx).

Answer (score 0):

You need to rebuild the indexes when you upgrade to or past 1.7 as noted here: http://nexus.sonatype.org/upgrading-nexus.html